# Error while using custom events in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, error, vs-code, lightning-events

I am trying to setup child to parent communication in lwc but i get error
No MODULE named markup://c:customEventChild found : [markup://c:customEventParent]

CustomChildEvent.html

```
<template>
<span style="margin-left:1em;">
 <lightning-button label="child" 
                   variant="brand" 
                   onclick={handleClick}>
 </lightning-button>
</span>
</template>
```

CutsomChildEvent.js

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class CustomEventChild extends LightningElement {
    @track test = 'value received from child';
    handleClick(event){
        const storeEvent = new CustomEvent('myevent',{detail: this.test});
    
        this.dispatchableEvent(storeEvent);
    }
}
```

CustomParenetEvent.html

```
<template>
<lightning-card>
<div> 
 <h1 style='font-size:1.5em; margin-left:45%;' 
     class="slds-text-title">
  This is parent screen
 </h1>
  <br/> 
<span style="font-size:2em;margin-left:30%;">
 This is response from child : 
<span style="color:#ffa372;">
 {response}
 </span> 
</span> 
 </br>
</div>
 <hr> 
<c-custom-event-child onmyevent={handleResponse}>
</c-custom-event-child>
</lightning-card>
```

CustomParentEvent.js

```
import { LightningElement ,track} from 'lwc';
export default class CustomEventParent extends LightningElement{
    @track response = '';
    //here we handled the event
     handleResponse(event){
        this.response = event.detail;
       console.log('Event =>>'+JSON.stringify(event));
     }
}
```

Comment: Please show the actual child component usage in the parent template.

Comment: i have edited this post ...you can view child component in parent

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using *precisely* the file names mentioned in your question, this is a problem. LWC names *must* start with a lowercase letter, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_components_folder).

> - Must begin with a lowercase letter
> - Must contain only alphanumeric or underscore characters
> - Must be unique in the namespace
> - Can’t include whitespace
> - Can’t end with an underscore
> - Can’t contain two consecutive underscores
> - Can’t contain a hyphen (dash)

Answer (score 1):

You have made an error in your CustomParenetEvent.html file where you are trying to use CustomChildEvent

The code should be

```
<c-custom-child-event onmyevent={handleResponse}>
</c-custom-child-event>
```

This explains why you are getting error No MODULE named markup://c:customEventChild found : [markup://c:customEventParent]

As stated by sfdcfox you need to be careful with naming as LWC is unforgiving in the naming aspect.